# Table is index/full scanned based on the table it is joined to

Tags: oracle, database-indexes

Table is index/full scanned based on the table it is joined to

Here, Table A is scanned using index

```
select * from B 
inner join A ON A.ID = B.ID
where
B.ID = '&ID';
```

but when I change it like this

```
select * from C 
inner join A ON A.ID = C.ID
where
C.ID = '&ID';
```

Table A is fully scanned and this is impacting performance

Stats are gathered for all these tables and their Indexes. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: How many rows in B match the predicate?  How many rows in A have the same `ID`?  How many rows in C match the predicate?  How many rows in A have the same `ID`?  How many rows in A?  How do all those actual values compare to the optimizer's cardinality estimates?  What are the actual query plans (with estimated and actual cardinalities preferrably)?  How do you know that full scanning A is bad?  Have you used a hint to force an index access and verified that it is indeed faster?

Comment: So you're saying that both queries return 1.4 million rows for a single `ID` value passed in?  One row from B and 1.43 million rows from A for the second query and one row from C and 1.43 million rows from A in the second query?  Are you looking at the cost in the query plan or the actual execution statistics?

Comment: C has 1408549 matching rows with A
B has 1437026 matching rows with A
Cost spikes from 3 to 14900. Cardinality 1 to 1,474,570. I expect an index scan  as I'm joining it on a column which is indexed.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure if you deleted and re-posted your comment or if you made some edits before reposting that aren't obvious to me.  Are you saying that both queries return a bit more than 1.4 million rows?

Comment: @JustinCave, for a valid single ID query returns only one row I told the no.of matching rows since you asked it. All the cost and cardinality I mentioned is from execution statistics

Comment: OK.  So only 1 row in B matches the predicate, only 1 row in C matches the predicate, and there is a single row in A that has the same `id` value as the B or C row?  Can you post both plans including the actual and estimated cardinalities?  You say that you've gathered statistics but it sounds like the statistics that are present are incorrect.  Can you post exactly how you gathered the statistics?

Comment: @JustinCave, i used dbms_stats.gather_index_stats and dbms_stats.gather_index_stats for index and tables statistics respectively. statistics are available in https://send.firefox.com/download/2ba93c388abc81c4/#X6rHYrcjeZV_nJnU-D_nBA

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the content?  Can you post the exact `dbms_stats` calls you made?  Looking at the query plans, I'm assuming that the shared table A is really a materialized view not a table.  Is that right?  Does the problem reproduce when you have an actual table rather than a materialized view?

Comment: These are the dbms_stats calls I made                                                            
begin
DBMS_STATS.gather_index_stats(SCHEMA, index_name);
end;

begin
DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats(SCHEMA, table_name);
end;  I can try having A as a actual table but 2 things to be noted table A is technically a table and if there is a problem with table A it should be universal I mean all joins on table A should have this problem but what we are noticing something different when I join it with different table, Hope it is clear

Comment: Hi @JustinCave, I created an actual table created indexes identical to A it has same behaviour as A. I feel I'm missing something on table C as this issue shows only when I join it with table C as cited in issue description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like oracle will use the index only if datatype of joins are similar. In my case c.ID was a varchar2 and A.ID was an integer.